# Error when initializing heap-allocated object

Tags: c++, object, initialization

I am trying to initialize a heap-allocated object as follows:

```
class Ball {
  int radius;
  string colour;
};

int main(){
    Ball *b = new Ball { radius = 5, colour = "red" };
}
```

Wondering why this is giving me an error?
Thanks

Comment: Please pick up a [Good Book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: If you have a c++0x compiler, have a look here at initializer lists http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11. If you have a c++98 compiler... Anyway in both ways your code is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many issues!

Try this:

```
class Ball {
public:
  Ball(int r, const string &s)
  {
    radius = r;
    colour = s;
  }
  int radius;
  string colour;
};

int main(){
    Ball *b = new Ball(5, "red");
    // ....
    // delete b;  <-- dont forget
}
```

Comment: @Pubby: The question tagged by _c++_, not _c++11_.

Comment: I'm talking about in the constructor. `Ball(int r, const string &s) : radius(r), colour(s) {}`

Comment: Ummm, yes, we can use this style too.

Comment: @MasoudM. It isn't just a style, you know.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how you initialize an object in C++.

Here's one way to do it:

```
class Ball {
    int radius;
    string colour;

public:

    //  Define a Constructor
    Ball(int _radius, const string &_colour)
        : radius(_radius)
        , colour(_colour)
    {
    }
};

int main(){
    Ball *b = new Ball(5, "red");

    delete b;  //  Don't forget to free it.
}
```

Comment: Why the `_`s? No ambiguity without them.

Comment: Probably more like "reader" ambiguity. But you're right, it does actually work without the `_`. I was under the impression that the parameters will shadow the fields, but I guess it doesn't apply to initializer lists.

Answer (score 0):

Use `()` instead of `{}`. You're calling a constructor, which is just a special function that instantiates an object.

So, the syntax looks like this:

`Ball* b = new Ball(5, "red");`

Also note that the parameter order in the constructor (5 before "red") dictates which variable get assigned to which value. So, you don't put the variable name in the constructor call.

Answer (score 0):

When creating an object use `( ... )` in place of `{ ... }` and no need to write variable name. just pass the value to be assigned.

```
Ball *b = new Ball { radius = 5, colour = "red" };` // Wrong
```

change it to

```
Ball *b = new Ball ( 5, "red" );
```

and, don't forget to declare `a constructor` in your `Ball` class, in `public` section.

```
Ball(int, std::string);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in C++11:

```
struct Ball {
  int radius;
  std::string colour;
};

int main() {
  Ball* b = new Ball({ 5, "red" });
}
```